# Как в Input заменить все пробелы на тире (-) PHP, JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, вёрстка

Есть форма, в ней input, как в **реальном времени** (**когда пользователей пишет что-то в input**) все пробелы **заменялись на тире**?

Сам input:

```
<div class="col-12">
 input id="url" type="text" class="form__input" name="urlfilm"  placeholder="URL страницы" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[name="urlfilm"]');

input.addEventListener('input', () =>
{
  input.value = input.value.replaceAll(' ', '-');
});
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
 <input id="url" type="text" class="form__input" name="urlfilm"  placeholder="URL страницы" >
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Oliver.